# Field 'id' doesn't have a default value because of nested object creation

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am getting field 'id' doesn't have a default value error in my Spring application.
I am trying to create an Applicant with @Post method but as I am creating the Applicant, new creditRating object needs to be created.

Here is the method

```
 public Applicant create(ApplicantDTO applicantDTO) {
        Applicant applicant = ApplicantMapper.toEntity(applicantDTO);
        applicant.setCreditRating(creditRatingService.create());
        return applicantRepository.save(applicant);
    }
```

Here is my Applicant class

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "applicant")
public class Applicant {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private Long identificationNumber;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private double monthlyIncome;
    private String phoneNumber;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "credit_rating_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private CreditRating creditRating;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "applicant_credit",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "applicant_id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "credit_id")}
    )
    private Credit credit;


}
```

And this is the create method for CreditRating object.

```
 public CreditRating create() {
        CreditRating creditRating = new CreditRating();
        creditRating.setCreditRating(getRandomCreditRating());
        return creditRatingRepository.save(creditRating);
    }
```

I want this object to be created while creating an Applicant but somehow I think JPA can't generate the id for it as I am doing the creation like this.

As requested here is CreditRating Entity

```
@Data
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "credit_rating")
public class CreditRating {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private int creditRating;

}
```

Comment: Can you post `CreditRating` entity?

Comment: @Pp88 I edited the question. Can you please check?

Comment: How are you generating your ids with a sequence? Have you set autoincrecment column on database? Witch database are you using?

Comment: Using MySQL. JPA automatically creates the tables. @Pp88

Comment: It doesn't seemed there's anything wrong with existing code, have you log out the result of `creditRatingService.create()` and see if id is generated and check db to see if data is persisted as well.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem. Problem was in database creditRating and credit somehow didn't have Auto Increment ticked. I dropped the schema then let JPA create the tables again. Then Auto Increment was both ticked on credit and creditRating tables.